# Ajax $.post("../application/controller/theScript.php" is appended to site root and not relative

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a set of email functions something like what is below for popping up a window that will send emails.

.add sends a post request to the userController and returns the VIEW that is the email window.

.init is called and sets up the handlers for the email window.

.send is called when the send button is pressed in the email window to send the email.

```
var Email={
con:"../application/controllers/",
dialog:null,

init:function(){..
//add event handlers for email dialog

send:function(){
    var emailType=$("#emailType").prop("value");

    var email=$("#email").prop("value");
    if(!email){this.error("Please provide a valid email address");return false}

    var emailTitle=$("#emailTitle").prop("value");
    if(!emailTitle){this.error("Please provide a valid email title");return false}

    var emailBody=$("#emailBody").prop("value");
    if(!emailBody){this.error("Please provide a valid email body");return false}

    if(emailType && email && emailTitle && emailBody){
        $.post(Email.con+"userController.php",{
            sendMail:"true",
            emailType:emailType,
            email:email,
            emailTitle:emailTitle,
            emailBody:emailBody,
        });

        return true;
    }

    return false;
},

add:function(id){
        $("#"+id).on("click",function(e){
        $.post(Email.con+"userController.php",{
            showMail:"true",
            emailType:this.dataset.emailType,
        },
        function(data,status){
            if(status==='success'){
                $("body").append(data);
                Email.init();
            }
        });
    });

    return this;
},

}
```

The problem is with the send function as the path in the $.post ajax call is not correct. When add is called it finds the userController which is in a folder system something like

- application

  - controllers
    -userController.php
- public

So the path "../application/controllers/userController.php" steps back one out of public and down the path to the controller.

In send the path is always appended to the site root or public folder and returns something like http://theSite/application/controllers/userController.php

Why is the send ajax call not using a relative path from the site root to the controller in the once case?

There must be 50 other ajax calls that work correctly on the site.

Comment: if your url does not start with a slash it will be relative to the current page.

Comment: I tried changing the path to "/../application/controllers/userController.php" and it still does the same thing. And once again, every other place that I make ajax calls the path is "../application/controllers/someController.php" and it works.

Comment: and I tried "/application.. still no love.

Comment: Where is `application` within site directory structure?

Comment: application is parallel to public and not in public. For ever other ajax call on the site I use "../application/controllers" to get out of public and back into application.

Answer (score 1):

The ajax.post request goes to a Url, and not to a file path.
It depends on the rewrites active on the Apache, and the php router in place, which file is associated to which Url.
I don't know what framework you are using, but it's very unlikely to use requests like http://theSite/application/controllers/userController.php .
Most likely it should be something like http://theSite/user, or maybe http://theSite/user.php, or in your code
$.post(Email+"/user",{
...
}

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the "email window" is loaded from a different URL therefore upon triggering send the path is interpreted differently by the browser. Try setting `con` to `"/application/controllers/"` to see if that solves the problem. If not, I would check the URL of the window that is popped up in the browser as it may be loading from a slightly different URL, hence, why the relative path works for `add` but not `send`.

Comment: Tried that path as well and it does not work. 

From the email window "window.location.pathname" returns "/"

Comment: And when you say "loading from a different url" it is loading in the same way that the rest of the site loads and that is from application/views usually via application/controllers, application/models and that will return an application/view. Once again calls to the controllers via ajax work in all cases but this one.

Comment: Something must be different in that scenario. I find it odd that "window.location.pathname" returns "/". Using Chrome or some other developer tools I would set a break point in your send code at `$.post(Email.con+"userController.php",{`. Once stopped here I would use the console to set `Email.con` and experiment with different variations of the URL.

Comment: Any combination of path that I tried results in some variation of http://theSite/application... and not ../

Comment: if I console.log(window.location) right before each ajax call I get exactly the same returned data. Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: ../ is not a path but simply an indicator to the browser to step back in the path 2 segments. Is this email window a new browser window or a tab or is it some inline markup that is shown as a modal?

Comment: It is just inline that has been added via $("body").append(data); in the Email.add function.
I understand that the "../" is indicating to go back one folder and this method works in all other ajax calls on the site. In fact Email.add is using this very same path to call the very same controller as Email.send is. 
As you can see from above the Email.add function gets calls the controller that calls the model that returns the view and it is then added to the page. Once added to the page in the success function the Email.init function is called that adds the event handlers for the new email.

Comment: Do you have any way to make this publically available to be able to see the problem in action?

Comment: Just getting back to this. Are you saying that using relative paths is not something that is normally done with Ajax? I'm new to web development but I remember doing this in tutorials long the way. Works perfectly in my local development server but I guess something is different on the public server. So is doing a relative path "../con..." a bad idea in the first place? If so I can move those controllers to a path down stream of the js folder.

Comment: "../con..." isn't a bad idea. I personally prefer to start with a '/' (excluding the dots) so I always know I'm starting from the root. If it works on your local and not on the server I would focus on difference in the URL used for your local vs. server. If you have some place this is available online it would be much easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Still getting everything working online and what I have done is create a controllers folder in public and any ajax controller that is needed is going in there so I can use "/controllers/someController.php" as the path and it works as it should. Is this a good solution to the problem in terms of security and work flow? Are there any major issues I will have to consider with this structure?